# how to know the number of files in a directory and all its subdirectories with a putty command line?

Tags: shell, command-line

I am using Putty, and I have a folder with lots of subfolders and files in each.  I need a command to know the size of the whole folder with all what's in it, and the number of total files for all that folder.

I know this command

> du -h foldername

but it lists the size of each and every subfolder, then gives the size of the total folder, but the number is not exact (i.e. shows 7.8G instead of how many bytes exactly), and doesn't show the number of total files.

Comment: Which terminal software you use is hardly relevant. The OS and shell on the server would be good to mention. All the replies will probably assume Linux and Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend is "find", along with "wc" which counts lines.

find foldername -type f | wc -l

If you want file sizes, du -k instead of -h will show you size in k. You also have the option of piping to ls -l, and summarizing the byte counts using a quick awk or perl script

Answer (score 0):

Get the total size in kilobytes:

```
du -sk foldername
```

Get the file count:

```
find foldername -type f | wc -l
```